# Multiline Latex equation alignment

Tags: equations, alignment, formulas

I have equation on two lines with a label (number of equation). However, the lines are aligned to the right and I would rather have then left-aligned. I have tried align* and gather*, but I haven't got the desired results. Also in these cases, I have been unable to see the label, which I very much want to include.

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:adj_BH}
\begin{split}
    q_{(K)} = \frac{N}{K} p_{(K)},\\ 
    q_{(i)} = min(\frac{N}{i} p_{(i)}, q_{(i + 1)} ) \, for \, i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, K-1\},
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions to fix this issue :)

Comment: How should it know where to align when you don't tell it to? use `&=`

Comment: use `&` before the `=` but also it is usually better to use `aligned` rather than `split` unless you really need the features of `split`.

Comment: also use `\min` not `min` and `\text{ for }`  never use math italic for words.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the problem :) Also, good point to add \min, not min

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of two fixes.

- The minimalist approach: Keep the OP's basic `split`-based structure, but provide alignment points, use text mode where appropriate, replace `min` with `\min`, and enlarge the "outer" parentheses in row 2.
- Switch from the `split` setup to a `cases`-enviroment setup.

Both fixes are implemented below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' and 'cases' environments and '\text' macro
\usepackage{xcolor}  % for '\textcolor' command
\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{OP's code}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:adj_BH}
\begin{split}
    q_{(K)} = \frac{N}{K} p_{(K)}\,,\\ 
    q_{(i)} = min(\frac{N}{i} p_{(i)}, q_{(i + 1)} ) 
       \, for \, i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, K-1\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\bigskip
\textcolor{red}{Solution 1: minimalist fixes}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:adj_BH}
\begin{split}
    q_{(K)} &= \frac{N}{K} \, p_{(K)}\,,\\ 
    q_{(i)} &= \min\Bigl(\frac{N}{i}\,p_{(i)}, q_{(i + 1)} \Bigr) 
       \text{ for $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, K-1\}$}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\bigskip
\textcolor{red}{Solution 2: Switch to a \texttt{cases} environment}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:adj_BH}
q_{(i)} = 
\begin{cases}
  \min\bigl((N/i)p_{(i)}, q_{(i + 1)} \bigr) &\text{for $i<K$}\,, \\
  (N/K)p_{(K)} &\text{for $i=K$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great! I like a lot the suggestion of using cases environment as well

Answer (score 4):

You should use `aligned`, rather than `split` (which is semantically not apt to the job). Alternatively, assign two different numbers.

I'd opt for `\tfrac`, because `\frac{N}{K}` is too prominent.

Note `\min`, the use of `\text` and `\dots` instead of `\ldots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Two equations with a single number for both
\begin{equation} \label{eq:adj_BH}
\begin{aligned}
    q_{(K)} &= \tfrac{N}{K} p_{(K)},\\ 
    q_{(i)} &= \min\bigl(\tfrac{N}{i} p_{(i)}, q_{(i + 1)} \bigr)
               \quad\text{for } i \in \{1, 2, \dots, K-1\},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
But one can also think to assign different, albeit linked numbers
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:adj_BH-again}
\begin{align}
    q_{(K)} &= \tfrac{N}{K} p_{(K)},\\ 
    q_{(i)} &= \min\bigl(\tfrac{N}{i} p_{(i)}, q_{(i + 1)} \bigr)
               \quad\text{for } i \in \{1, 2, \dots, K-1\},
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
and we can refer to either equation~\eqref{eq:adj_BH}
or to equations~\eqref{eq:adj_BH-again}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The subequations with linked numbers look very useful